# How to unlock “Classic Mode — Final Results” music?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

In *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate*, there is a song that plays on the “Final Results” screen when you beat Classic Mode. It is a solo piano arrangement of Lifelight that is over two minutes and forty five seconds long (I timed it).

It is a distinct version from [“Classic Mode — Defeat”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69wnPb6mc8E); the voicings are different, it is much longer, and it has a distinct end. It is completely different from [the song called “Classic Mode — Final Results”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tF3PpklQ1os) in My Music.

Is there any way to unlock this song? I currently own every song from the shop (but I haven't beaten World of Light.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is the song you are looking for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l46aZE669nM). It's called Main Theme Piano Solo.

In order to unlock it, you have to get the [True Ending](https://www.ign.com/wikis/super-smash-bros-ultimate/How_to_Get_the_True_Ending).